# What is OptionSet in Swift?

Tags: swift

I was trying to find `directions` of `UIPanGestureRecognizer`
and I got one extension of it where one `struct` is using `OptionSet` like that:

```
extension UIPanGestureRecognizer {
    public struct PanGestureDirection: OptionSet {
        public let rawValue: UInt8

        public init(rawValue: UInt8) {
            self.rawValue = rawValue
        }

        static let Up = PanGestureDirection(rawValue: 1 << 0)
        static let Down = PanGestureDirection(rawValue: 1 << 1)
        static let Left = PanGestureDirection(rawValue: 1 << 2)
        static let Right = PanGestureDirection(rawValue: 1 << 3)
    }

    private func getDirectionBy(velocity: CGFloat, greater: PanGestureDirection, lower: PanGestureDirection) -> PanGestureDirection {
        if velocity == 0 {
            return []
        }
        return velocity > 0 ? greater : lower
    }

    public func direction(in view: UIView) -> PanGestureDirection {
        let velocity = self.velocity(in: view)
        let yDirection = getDirectionBy(velocity: velocity.y, greater: PanGestureDirection.Down, lower: PanGestureDirection.Up)
        let xDirection = getDirectionBy(velocity: velocity.x, greater: PanGestureDirection.Right, lower: PanGestureDirection.Left)
        return xDirection.union(yDirection)
    }
}
```

Can anyone can help me in simple terms with simple example of what exactly is `OptionSet` and how we can use it in future tasks?

Comment: FYI - `OptionSet` is not a keyword, it's a name of a protocol.

Comment: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#SECoptionsSets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straight from the source:

"A type that presents a mathematical set interface to a bit set."

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optionset